# Как проверить есть ли определенный класс у родительского компонента во Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Например, есть родительский компонент с параметрами, который отрисовывает несколько элементов (инпутов):

```
<template v-else v-for="field of dynamicFields">
            <service-field
              :key="field.name"
              v-model="field.value"
              v-bind="field"
              :label=field.label
              :rules="field.rules"
              :placeholder="field.placeholder"
              :name="field.name"
              :readonly="field.readonly"
              class="dynamic-form-fields__field"
              :class="{
                'dynamic-form-fields__field_full-width': field.fullWidth,
                'dynamic-form-fields__field_bitpro24': theme === 'bitpro24'
              }"
            />
          </template>
```

А внутри ServiceField:

```
<template>
  <div class="service-field">
    <label :for="id" class="service-field__label">{{ label || name || '' }}</label>
    <v-text-field
      :id="id"
      v-mask="input_mask || '~'"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      :rules="rules"
      :value="textValue"
      validate-on-blur
      outlined
      :disabled="readonly"
      v-on="$listeners"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
  import { mask } from "../../spa/common/directives";

  export default {
    name: "ServiceField",
    inheritAttrs: true,
    directives: { mask },
    props: {
      name: { type: String, default: null },
      label: { type: String, default: null },
      rules: { type: Array, default: null },
      regex: { type: String, default: null },
      input_mask: { type: String, default: null },
      min_length: { type: Number, default: null },
      max_length: { type: Number, default: null },
      required: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      readonly: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      placeholder: { type: String, default: null },
      value: null
    },
    data() {
      return {
        menu: false,
        id: null,
      };
    },
    computed: {
      textValue: {
        get() {
          return this.value;
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.id = uuidv4();
    }
  };
</script>
```

Нужно отобразить собственный `label` для инпута у корневого элемента которого `div.service-field` есть класс `dynamic-form-fields__field_full-width`. Сейчас `label` отображается для всех инпутов с данными, которые пришли от родительского компонента. Но именно для одного из них, нужно сделать свой `label`, а у остальных оставить как есть.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще по-хорошему бы просто передавать свойство через `props` отдельно, вы же знаете, что из этого должно быть на полный экран, а что нет.

Если вы всё же хотите поизвращаться, Вам стоит посмотреть, что вообще приходит в дочерний компонент. Для этого можно просто в `mounted()` вывести в консоль объект из `this`:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

В ответ получите что-то такое: [image: Результат вывода this]

При внимательном изучении можно найти `$vnode`, в котором записываются вычисленные классы и другая информация об узле.

Собственно, решением будет создание вычисляемого свойства, в Вашем случае:

```
computed: {
    fullWidth() {
      return this.$vnode.data?.class?.["dynamic-form-fields__field_full-width"];
    },
},
```

По этому свойству уже можете выводить что хотите по условию.

Comment: Пример в песочнице: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wildflower-jmt550